# Spring: Not able to write to Autowired repository when using TimerTask

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, timertask

I have a method that should periodically update records in a database.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    private Boolean flag = false;

    @Transactional
    public int method1(Args args) {
        //  do something
        if (!flag) {
            method2()
        }
        return x;
    }

    @Transactional
    public int method2(Args args) {
        polling = true;
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<Records> records = myRepository.getRecords()

                for (Record record : records ) {

                    // prints the Id of each record. Now, they are all have Id=1
                    System.out.println(record.getId());

                    // setting the record's Id to 5
                    record.setId(5);

                    // prints '5'
                    System.out.println(record.getId());
               }

            }
        }, 10, 1000*60*4
    }
}
```

Method1 calls Method2. Method2 executes the code inside the run() function every 4 minutes. The code inside run() works properly without scheduling (gets the Ids for each record, prints them, updates the db by setting Id to 5). 
However, now, with my use of TimerTask, it still retrieves and prints the Ids, supposedly sets each record's Id to 5, and even prints out '5' at record.get(Id) which would lead me to believe the database was successfully updated with the new Id. 
When I actually check my database, I find that the Ids actually haven't been updated to 5. The original Ids remain. 
I'm not sure why this is happening, as it seemed like the Ids were being updated. Is this something to do with TimerTask creating a new thread?

Comment: You're spinning off a `TimerTask` from *inside* an `@Transactional` method, but your task method isn't transactional itself. Use `@Scheduled` instead.

Comment: Used @Scheduled and got it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The @Transational assumes that it is going to wrap ONE TRANSACTION against the DB, so you need to have your @Transactional functions where they do one thing, let and get out immediately. You know the DB will have either committed or rolled back. Depending on Transaction Isolation levels (another topic you may want to research, but probably don't need to) the thnigs that go on inside the @Transactional never get written to db until that function actually returns. That's probably all you are missing. Chrylis is right to use @Scheduled for 'repeating things' but the real problem is the one i stated, with all due respect to him/her.

Summary: Make your @Scheduled function call a @Transactional function (for each DB transaction you want to do), and then it will work.